# Flipped copy of a Rectangle using ScaleTransform in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a flipped copy of a rectangle in Left, Right, Up and Down directions.

However I am able to do it when the selected rectangle has no prior transformation applied on it.

But once a rectangle is being transformed with `ScaleTransform` and I try to flip it again in the desired direction, the solution does not work for me.

Please correct me what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the code I am using

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="LightGray" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" Height="60" Width="100" Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="300" MouseDown="rect_MouseDown">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFB7D0E" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF59C103" Offset="1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.51" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">           
        <Button Content="Left" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="Right" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="Up" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="Down" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>               
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
    Rectangle selectedRect;

    //Flip
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedRect == null)
            return;

        //Create a copy of rectangle
        string rectXaml = XamlWriter.Save(selectedRect);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(rectXaml);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        Rectangle newRect = (Rectangle)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

        //Calculate the bounding box
        var boundingRect = newRect.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, newRect.Width, newRect.Height));

        double cX, cY, sX, sY;
        sX = 1;
        sY = 1;
        cX = (boundingRect.Left + boundingRect.Right) / 2;
        cY = (boundingRect.Top + boundingRect.Bottom) / 2;  

        switch ((sender as Button).Content.ToString())
        {
            case "Up":
                sX = 1;
                sY = -1;
                cY = boundingRect.Top;
                break;

            case "Down":
                sX = 1;
                sY = -1;
                cY = boundingRect.Bottom;
                break;

            case "Left":
                sX = -1;
                sY = 1;
                cX = boundingRect.Left;
                break;

            case "Right":
                sX = -1;
                sY = 1;
                cX = boundingRect.Right;
                break;
        }

        newRect.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        newRect.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(sX, sY, cX, cY);            
        newRect.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rect_MouseDown);

        //Add new rect to Canvas
        canvas.Children.Add(newRect);
    }

    //To select a rectangle on canvas
    private void rect_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedRect != null)
            selectedRect.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

        selectedRect = sender as Rectangle;
        selectedRect.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    //clear the selection
    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedRect != null)
        {
            selectedRect.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            selectedRect = null;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue in your code was that you were trying to flip again the flipped, but the transform used was not not flipped. also the canvas location were not set properly to get the desired.

I did try to rewrite your code, this approach will flip the rectangle from the center and will move via canvas location properties i.e. left & top

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedRect == null)
            return;

        //Create a copy of rectangle
        string rectXaml = XamlWriter.Save(selectedRect);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(rectXaml);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        Rectangle newRect = (Rectangle)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

        double cX, cY, sX, sY;
        sX = 1;
        sY = 1;
        cX = newRect.Width / 2;
        cY = newRect.Height / 2;

        double top = Canvas.GetTop(selectedRect);
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(selectedRect);

        switch ((sender as Button).Content.ToString())
        {
            case "Up":
                sX = 1;
                sY = -1;
                top -= selectedRect.Height;
                break;

            case "Down":
                sX = 1;
                sY = -1;
                top += selectedRect.Height;
                break;

            case "Left":
                sX = -1;
                sY = 1;
                left -= selectedRect.Width;
                break;

            case "Right":
                sX = -1;
                sY = 1;
                left += selectedRect.Width;
                break;
        }
        Canvas.SetLeft(newRect, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(newRect, top);

        newRect.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        ScaleTransform trans = newRect.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
        if (trans != null)
        {
            //flip the previous transform
            trans.ScaleX *= sX;
            trans.ScaleY *= sY;
        }
        else
        {
            //create a new if none
            trans = new ScaleTransform(sX, sY, cX, cY);
        }
        newRect.RenderTransform = trans;
        newRect.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rect_MouseDown);

        //Add new rect to Canvas
        canvas.Children.Add(newRect);

        //optional to set the new rect as selected for continuous flip copy
        newRect.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left) { RoutedEvent = Rectangle.MouseDownEvent });
    }
```

give it a try, see if this is what you are looking for. I would suggest you to go for data binding, that will make things lot easier.